# Maximum and minimum plotted on a curve

Tags: plotting, color

Through code:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}] = x^4 + y^4 + z^4;

r[t_] = {1/3 + 1/3 Cos[t] - 1/Sqrt[3] Sin[t],
         1/3 + 1/3 Cos[t] + 1/Sqrt[3] Sin[t],
         1/3 - 2/3 Cos[t]};
{min, max} = {0, 2 Pi};

ParametricPlot3D[
 r[t],
 {t, min, max},
 ColorFunction -> Function[t, 
   ColorData["Rainbow"][f[r[t]]]],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow",
    {MinValue[{f[r[t]], min <= t <= max}, t],
     MaxValue[{f[r[t]], min <= t <= max}, t]}}]]
```

I get:

[image]

which it is certainly not what you want, because through this other code:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x^4 + y^4 + z^4;

A = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x + y + z <= 1, {x, y, z}];

SliceDensityPlot3D[
 f[x, y, z],
 BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[A],
 {x, y, z} \[Element] DiscretizeRegion[A],
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 AxesLabel -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I get:

[image]

where the colors are very clear that it must be expected on the circumference above.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Which minimum should be colored? Minimum t, min x, y, z, min length to point p/origin? (And try: `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`)

Comment: Btw, note that your definition of functions should use `SetDelayed` if you define variables as patterns: `f[x_,y_,z_]:=...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, color data is scaled such that it uses the entire range of the applied color function. To avoid this, set `ColorFunctionScaling->False`. Furthermore, `ColorFunction`, according to the documentation, should be a function of  `x,y,z,u` (where `u` is `t` in your code). So here is the full call:

```
ParametricPlot3D[r[t], {t, min, max}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z, t}, ColorData["Rainbow"][f[r[t]]]],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {MinValue[{f[r[t]], min <= t <= max}, t], 
     MaxValue[{f[r[t]], min <= t <= max}, t]}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Manu: see updated code